# How does Twitter app make both title and icon clickable in ActionBar?

Tags: android, twitter, android-actionbar

I've been wondering about this question quite long time. How do they do that? Is the title just disabled and the HomeAsUp button is custom and contains the logo, arrow and text?

Do you know any other ways how to accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by making a single image that contain both
- arrow.
- text.
- icon.
And the work on this single image action

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted to hear. Thanks.